# How flipkart is accessing dom elements for integration testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selenium, integration-testing

I just noticed, Flipkart has mostly classes with random names( not sure it is static or changes with every build ) in their dom elements like we get using styled-components library.

I just want to know, how are they accessing the dom element for the integration testing?

**UPDATED:** For accessing elements using a testing framework like selenium, which locator(id, classes, xpath) they are using? 
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53150917/edit).

Comment: I have updated the question, actually, I want to know how we can access the dom elements in testing framework, when we are not giving ids, classes are random names.

Comment: Nobody but flipart team can tell you that. If your question is applicable to other applications that expose similar behaviour, consider updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

Random class names and other element identifiers can be useful to prevent application misuse, particularly crawling and ad blocking. This also prevents the application from being efficiently debugged and tested.

A good practice is to provide debug mode that will result in determinate identifiers. For instance, identifiers could be pseudo-random and be hashed with specified salt in debug mode, `randomize('foo')` would result in same string in test environment, console and the application itself:

```
function randomize(identifier) {
  return hash(DEBUG_MODE ? getSpecifiedSalt() : getRandomSalt() + identifier);
}
```